# How do I model a simple Event Reminders app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I'm building a small event reminders app in Rails - you can see a list of live streams happening in the future, go to each event page, and add a phone # to be reminded about that event 5 minutes before it happens, with a link to the livestream itself.

What is the best way to model this? I was thinking 'Events' with the event details, 'Reminders' with an event_id and phone# attached. Also was thinking of using Active Job for the background processing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cron job to check about the event and reminder him before 5 minutes
and check about if event will remind more than one.